# Pam: How do I restrict users from using old password using pam?

Tags: password, pam

I am currently using Ubuntu server 20.04.1.

As stated in the title, I would like to configure pam so that users cannot use 5 old passwords. I have followed some guide on ways to do it but none of it work. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to edit your `/etc/pam.d/common-password` File and append `use_authtok` to the password line that contains `pam_unix.so`:

```
password    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so obscure sha512 use_authtok
```

Next, you’ll need to set the `pam_pwhistory.so` module and set the `remember` value to 5 (or however many your password policy demands):

```
password    required    pam_pwhistory.so  remember=5
```

Put this above the line you just edited.

Finally, it’s important that you confirm the existence of the `/etc/security/opasswd` file. This is where used passwords are stored. If the file does not exist, you can create it like this:

```
sudo touch /etc/security/opasswd
```

Make sure it is readable and writable only by `root` with:

```
sudo chmod 600 /etc/security/opasswd
```

These changes take effect immediately, as there is no pam daemon, so there’s nothing to restart or reload.

There’s [a lot more that pam can do](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/pam.conf.5.html) if you need more fine-grained control over the reuse, length, and complexity of passwords